# Fetching data in SQL using php

Tags: php, sql

I was just wondering how to display the HELLO HELLO HELLO in html, with the same format. 
[sample picture for the HELLO HELLO HELLO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWwhn.png)

```
 <td>'.$row["remarks"].'</td>
```

this doesn't seem to work, it just displays the HELLO HELLO HELLO in one line

Comment: provide your code. did you run loop?

Comment: use `<pre></pre>` or better `nl2br()`

Comment: [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) should helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content stored in your database has line breaks which when output onto a html page can not be read. Using pre is the most sensible suggestion.

```
echo sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>',$row["remarks"]);
```

You can optionally also use [str_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on the text to replace those line breaks with a br, [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)(on the LB)/[implode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)(with br) or [nl2br](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

There is numerous methods of acheiving your desired results so research what your best option is.

Comment: it did work! but how am I going to remove the </br> whenever I update and display my contents?

Comment: Do the opposite. When you extract from the database you convert from line breaks to br elements. Do the same but in reverse.

Comment: Hello, can you tell how to do it? I really have no clue. All I can see is the ereg_replace but they say is it was deprecated